# split dataframe values into a specified number of groups and apply function - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9])
```

I'd like to split `df` into a specified number of groups and sum all elements in each group. For example, dividing `df` into 4 groups

```
1,4,1,3  2,8,3,6  3,7,3,1  2,9
```

would result in

```
9
19
14
11
```

I could do `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4).sum()`, but this won't work for larger dataframes

For example

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9,1,5,3,4])
df1.groupby(np.arange(len(df1))//4).sum()
```

creates 5 groups instead of 4

Comment: What is problem in larger df with `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4).sum()` ? What is problem? For me works nice.

Comment: @jezrael: the problem with the second df is that it creates 5 groups [9 19 14 17 7] instead of 4

Comment: Test is by `print (pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9,1,5,3,4]).groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4)[0].apply(list))`, I think it works correct.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks, it works for the second dataframe, but it doesn't generalize to other dataframes like pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,3,3,1,3,1,3,1,4,2,1,3,1,3,12,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,4]). The problem is that I don't know in advance how many elements df will have so I was looking for a way to group every df into the same number of groups irrespective of the number of elements it has

Comment: I think I understand - still need `4` groups in each DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael: Yes, exactly. I'd like to create 4 groups, whether df has 16, 21, or 199 elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9,1,5,3,4])

a = pd.Series([x.values.sum() for x in np.array_split(df, 4)])
print (a)
0    11
1    27
2    15
3    13
dtype: int64
```

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and `sum`:

```
a = pd.concat(np.array_split(df, 4), keys=np.arange(4)).sum(level=0)
print (a)
    0
0  11
1  27
2  15
3  13
```

Comment: The output is'nt correct. Try also with `df=pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9])`  you'll get `[9, 19, 13, 12]` wich is not correct.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: for `df=pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9])` isn't the sum of 4 elements in each group returns `[9, 19, 13, 12]` ? with your code i got: `[11, 27, 15, 13]`.

Comment: Hmmmm, question is if need first 3 groups by `4` elements and `4. group` with all another elements (your solution) or split to `4 groups` with different count of elements of group especially if larger df.

Comment: @jezrael: Many thanks again for your help. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9])
```

You can achive it using list comprehension and `loc`:

```
group_size = 4
[df.loc[i:i+group_size-1].values.sum() for i in range(0, len(df), group_size)]
```

Output:

```
[9, 19, 14, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the comments, and i thought that you can use some explicit `python` code when the "usual" pandas functions can't fulfill your needs.

So:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_sum(a, chunks):
    for k in range(0, len(df), chunks):
        yield a[k:k+chunks].values.sum()

df = pd.DataFrame([1,4,1,3,2,8,3,6,3,7,3,1,2,9])

group_size = list(get_sum(df, 4))
print(group_size)
```

Output:

```
[9, 19, 14, 11]
```